# APIM ARM template creation

Tags: ibm-api-management

I have an APIM instance and API's working on it. I want to create ARM template for deployment but can't understand how to do it. I only have the Azure portal repository for it and don't want to create a VSO repository. I am new to ARM templates, so don't have much information.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your code like the arm templates or swagger files wherever you want, GitHub, Azure DevOps, locally only ... and then deploy your api using Api-M's REST interface (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/api/createorupdate), the PowerShell AzureRm or Az module https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.apimanagement/import-azurermapimanagementapi?view=azurermps-6.13.0 or by deploying an arm template.

When it comes to creating arm templates you may take a look here: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-azure-api-management-create/azuredeploy.json

Anyway, we first started with arm templates as well and found later out that it's easier to use the REST interface or the PowerShell module by deploying a swagger file and the policies.